# A better way to roll dice

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have a game that requires the player to roll two die.  As this is a multiplayer game, the way I currently do this is have 6 animations (1 for each die's outcome).  When the player clicks a button, it sends a request to my server code.  My server code determines the die's outcome and sends the results to the client.  The client then plays the corresponding animations.

This works ok, but has some issues.  For instance, if the server sends back two of the same values (two 6's, for example) then the animations don't work correctly.  As both animations are the same, they overlay each other, and it looks like only one die was rolled.

Is there a better way to do this?  Instead of animations, using "real" dice?  If that's the case, I always need to be sure to "pre-determine" the outcome of the dice roll, on the server.  I also need to make sure the dice don't fall off the table or jostle any of the other player pieces on the board.

thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Just a thought, could you not add an offeset to the two dice's starting locations so that even if the server returns the same value you end up with two animations (albeit identical ones) being shown.

Comment: Or mirror the animation to make it less obvious!

Comment: @Agumander Is it possible to offset an animation?  Where it starts and ends?

Comment: If the animation is relative to a parent object you can move the parent object to offset both the start and end by the same amount. As well as every point in between. If you want to change the start and end separately, you'd need to re-interpolate all the animation keyframes by script.

Comment: Honestly I'd create two animations for each result state. Variant 1 plays on the first die, variant 2 plays on the second die.

Comment: @Draco18s yes, that is what I was thinking.  Simulating physics on the server seems a bit overkill for this game

Comment: Oh definitely. Server only needs to care about the value result, not running physics calculations. Heck, know what you could do? Set up 12 different rolling animations, each one showing the same side landing face up (the same *actual* side) and then just before running the animation, tweaking the texture so that the sides change places.  Then you could run a random animation (though you still might want to keep A and B variants) but still get the desired outcome.

Comment: @Draco18s  that sound like an interesting approach but, being new to Unity, may be out of my league.  Would you know of any tutorials?  Also, if you post what you have as a response, I will mark it correct.

Comment: Will do in about a half hour. Writing code on a crowded bus does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server only needs to care about the value result, not running physics calculations.

Set up 12 different rolling animations:

- Six for the first die
- Six for the second die

Each one should always end with the same modeled face pointing upwards (the starting position isn't relevant, only the ending position).  For the latter steps you'll probably want to adjust the model's UV coordinates to use a very tall or very wide texture (or just a slice of a square one).  So *not* [like this](http://www.spookypeanut.co.uk/notes/MART/T2L07/MART_T2L07_html_m413184ba.png) but rather all in a line 1-2-3-4-5-6.

The next step is picking a random animation to play. You've already got code to run a given animation, just set it to pick randomly instead of based on the die-roll-value from the server:

```
int animNum = Mathf.Floor(Random.Next()*6);
```

Finally, the fun bit.  Adjusting the texture so that the *desired face* shows when the animation is done. I'm going to assume that you arrange your faces along the top edge of your square texture.  [Material.SetTextureOffset()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetTextureOffset.html).

```
int showFace = Mathf.Floor(Random.Next()*6); //this value should come from the server
die.renderer.material.SetTextureOffset(1f/6 * showFace,0);
```

This will set the texture offset such that the desired face will show on top.  You'll even be able to see it changing in the inspector.  Because of the UVs being arranged such that each face uses the next chunk over and because textures will wrap around when reaching the edge (unless the texture is set to Clamp in its import settings: you don't want this here).

Note that this will cause a new material instance to be instantiated (which is not very performant).  If you want to avoid this, you'll have to use [a material property block](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could simulate the physics on the server, keep track of the positions and the orientations of the dice for the duration of the animation, and then send the data over to the client. I understand it's a lot of data for something so simple, but that's one way you can get the rolls to appear realistic and synced between all clients.

If only Unity's physics was deterministic that would be a whole lot easier.

Comment: Unity's physics aren't deterministic?

Comment: @JamesHughes nope.

Comment: @JamesHughes It's all to do with floating point rounding errors. In practice, you can write a fully deterministic physics engine that replaces all floats with scaled ints. Who knows there might even already be one out there.

Comment: @JamesHughes [This](http://gafferongames.com/networked-physics/deterministic-lockstep/) is interesting.

Comment: I always assumed that would've been how they did it, since fundamentally physics should be entirely deterministic, I'll have a look at your link when I've finished my shift, it's blocked here.